Entire render is pink? Viewport shows things right


I have tried checking Render properties and output properties panel settings. Unable to solve the issue.

Solved it, there was a image sequence that was added to sequencer. And later deleted, which led to pink image while rendering.
Removing the missing image sequence made it work.

Wild guess, maybe you had a transparent texture or video on a plane, like smoke etc. and moved the file so now when rendering it shows pink.
Pink is it mostly when the texture is missing.
Alternatively you can go to File > External Data > Find missing files and then let it search your whole PC for the missing texture.

Yes, the files it is referring to is old render that I deleted. But, it is not rendering any new image.
